# No video on SV-3 instrument viewer

Tags: hdmi, display, video, config.txt

When I set the Pi (Zero) up with the required **640x480 60Hz** mode in *config.txt* the **SV-3** reports ***no signal***.

But if I plug a VGA **Acer** monitor in to the Pi and then unplug it, plugging in the **SV-3** works!

I am using a standard micro HDMI->HDMI converter with a HDMI->VGA converter (Branded Pi-Hut)

In the *config.txt* I have tried various combinations of

```
hdmi_safe=1

hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080

hdmi_group=1    CEA
hdmi_mode=1     VGA 640x480
hdmi_mode=2     480p 
hdmi_mode=3     480p H

hdmi_group=2    DMT
hdmi_mode=4     640x480 60 Hz
```

Then I tried plugging in the **Acer** monitor and running

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d edid.dat
```

putting *edid.dat* into */boot* and setting the

```
hdmi_edid_file=1
```

I also compared the *edid.dat* when just the **SV-3** was plugged in vs the **Acer** monitor (links to files at the end)

Running

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
```

for either VGA device gives

```
state 0x12000a [HDMI DMT (4) RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

and running X and then *randr* from a VT for both devices gives

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 576 x 416, current 576 x 416, maximum 576 x 416
default connected 576x416+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   576x416        0.00*
```

*get-edid* always reports *nothing on the i2c bus*

So I know it is the Pi doing something to the HDMI output when I plug in the **Acer** monitor that makes the **SV-3** work when it is plugged in afterwards. But it does not seem to be the ***edid*** so I am at a complete loss as to what to try now.

This is a strange setup so I appreciate any answers or ideas.

edid for the Acer monitor [text file](http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/misc/sv-3/acer.edid.txt)
edid for the SV-3 [text file](http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/misc/sv-3/sv-3.edid.txt)